# Visual Studio - Compile for 32 bit vista on 64 bit windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-vista, 32-bit

I am having a little trouble with a small Winform program I have created that uses Sqlite.

I have developed the program on a Windows 7 64 bit machine and compiled it using the Any CPU compile option.

Program uses .NET framework version 4, Vista PC has framework version 4 on it.

The output runs fine on my 64 bit Win 7 PC but on a 32 bit Vista machine it does not run.

I also tried Mixed platforms. Am I missing anything else in my compilation options to ensure this will run on a 32 bit platform?

Regards and thanks
John

Comment: Surely you have a better diagnostic than "does not run"?  SqlLite contains native code, you'll need its 32-bit version on a 32-bit machine.

Comment: Sorry I should have included the error message. The VS JIT debbuger says "An unhandled win32 exception occured in BBLM.exe [3592]"